# Encoding and decoding of JSF pages

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I am reading [Core JavaServer Faces 3rd edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137012896) and I got a question about the encoding and decoding of JSF pages.

When the page is about to be rendered it will first go through the XHTML page containing JSF tags. Each JSF tag has a own tag handler class and they co-operate to make the component tree of that page. All other tags is ignored.

Each component has a own renderer that knows how to generate the HTML. Now the book says:

(This is a h:inputText tag)

> Each component has a renderer that produces HTML output, reflecting the component state. The renderer of the UIInput object asks the JSF implementation to look up the unique ID and the current value fo the expression user.name.

The question is:

Why does the book say that the implementation asks for the current value of the expression `user.name`? I would expect that the implementation instead asked the component - in this case `UIInput` - which had some reference to this user bean instead? Because, doesn't that class "reflects" the JSF tag in code?

I probably have misunderstood the concept and I would like to learn it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the output value of an [`EditableValueHolder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/EditableValueHolder.html) like `UIInput`, a `Renderer` would typically call `getValue()`. This will generally return:

1. The value from `getSubmittedValue()` if input validation or conversion failed
2. The object set explicitly by calling `setValue(Object)` if any
3. The result of the `value` [`ValueExpression`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getValueExpression%28java.lang.String%29) if any

The component defines behaviour. Ideally, it should be loosely coupled to the renderers, markup and data sources. The component doesn't care what its data source is - it doesn't have to be a managed bean. Getting and setting values is the responsibility of the `ValueExpression`.

What the `ValueExpression` evaluates to depends on the [context](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/ValueExpression.html#getValue%28javax.el.ELContext%29).

Comment: Okey, just an additional question: the decoding face happens in the ApplyRequestVariables lifecycle stage right and the encoding in RenderResponse?

Comment: Yes. During _Apply Request Values_, the `Renderer.decode` will read the input (usually from the parameter map) and call `setSubmittedValue(Object)` on the component. The `Renderer.encode*(...)` methods are invoked to emit the markup via the `ResponseWriter` during _Render Response_.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters passed to JSF components are basically EL (expression language) expressions, and evaluating those can be a *lot* more complex than accessing some reference - The JSF EL is a [programming language of its own](http://developers.sun.com/docs/jscreator/help/jsp-jsfel/jsf_expression_language_intro.html), with syntax and semantics only indirectly related to Java.

Answer (score 0):

> I would expect that the implementation instead asked the component ?

In my opinion, `UIInput` components and bean's properties are 2 distinctive things. They do not have any relationships with each other until we bind the `value` attribute of the `UIInput` component to a property of the bean.

In other words, `UIInput` components by themselves do not have anythings so called *current values*. They are simply a *value displayer & getter*. So, the renderer will have to ask the JSF implementation (which is usually the `ManagedBean`), for the value that the `UIInput` components should display.

> ... UIInput - which had some reference to this user bean instead

In general, the relationship between `UIInput`, a property and JSF implementation (`ManagedBean`) should look like this: `UIInput` - `ManagedBean` - bean properties. The renderer needs to communicate with the man in the middle (`ManagedBean`) to get what it wants because `UIInput` does not have a direct relationship with bean's properties.

The above are my current understanding. Please correct me if I'm wrong! :)